# Can I share settings for IntelliJ Idea across different projects?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In the month or so that I've been using IntelliJ, I have one project that I am working in the majority of the time in which I have all of my windows, toolbar locations, etc., set up to my liking.

I infrequently need to open other projects in IntelliJ, and I notice when doing so that all of the window locations seem to reset to the default. For example, the Structure toolbar moves back to the lower-left hand of the screen; I prefer for it to be docked in the upper-right hand corner.

*Can settings for window and tool locations be shared across different IntelliJ projects*? Can I configure this once globally, and have it apply to any new project I open in IntelliJ going forward?

Also, does anyone know where these types of settings are stored - I assume it's in the per-project *IntelliJ* files (such as `.ipr`, etc) rather than my global `.settings` directory?

Answer (score 18):

1. Create new connection or go to connection "Properties" (Alt+ENTER)
2. Find "Project Data Sources" on top left
3. Select "Make Global" in context menu

Comment: This is the correct solution as of current version of IDE.

Answer (score 10):

For *IntelliJ-13/14*, if you want reuse the connection to databases and the appservers you should copy-paste these files between the `.idea` folders of the projects.

- `dataSources.ids`, `dataSources.xml` : Database stuff
- `workspace.xml` : All the appservers configuration

Yes, this sucks, but at least there is a workaround.

---

*EDIT*:
When you create/edit the datasource there is a combobox called "scope", you can select **IDE** option, and this will let you reuse the datasource across many projects.

Answer (score 6):

You are right, these settings are project specific and you can't make them default. They are stored in the `.idea/workspace.xml` or in the `<project>.iws` file depending on the project format you are using.

You can try to overwrite this file in the new project with the one from the old project so that your settings are transferred.

Comment: Does IntelliJ offer any way to sync these settings across projects?

Comment: No, it doesn't. You can submit a request at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA .