# How to run integration tests from IntelliJ context menu for gradle project?

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea, gradle

Using IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.2, I have imported a gradle java project.  We have set up a sourceSet and configuration to separate integration tests from unit tests. (our integration tests are in the test source tree, but in their own package).  Relevant bits from the build.gradle are:

```
sourceSets {
  test {
    java {
      exclude '**/it/**'
    }
  }

  integTest {
    java {
      srcDir 'src/test/java'
      include '**/it/**'
    }
    resources {
      srcDir 'src/test/resources'
    }
    compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output + configurations.testRuntime
    runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output + configurations.testRuntime
  }
}

configurations {
  integTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
  integTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}

idea {
  module {
    scopes.TEST.plus += [ configurations.integTestCompile ]
  }
}

task integTest(type: Test) {
  testClassesDir = sourceSets.integTest.output.classesDir
  classpath = sourceSets.integTest.runtimeClasspath
}
```

This works fine from the command line. But when I open up the source of an integration test in IntelliJ and right-click to run it, IntelliJ launches the "test" task rather than the "integTest" task.  How do I get IntelliJ to launch the correct task?

Alternatively, how can I make the test task delegate to another task based on the contents of the "--tests " arg?

Comment: I'm struggling with the exact same issue. Have you found any solution? Thanks!

Comment: Not yet.  I've had more pressing issues so this one is on the back burner for now.

Comment: Seems to still be a problem, I have the exact same situation, with Intellij 2017.3.3. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206174789-How-to-run-integration-tests-from-context-menu-for-gradle-project-

Answer (score 3):

Follow this: gradle settings > Gradle > Runner and check Delegate IDE build/run actions to gradle. Then apply and Ok.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the test on file and you should see a menu option for `Create Run Configuration >`.  Select that an in the dialog, modify the `Tasks` option. Change that to `integTest` and click OK.  From that point, you might have to run the test using the menu system rather than the context system.  i.e. `Run > Run...`

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no `integTest` option for me (using TestNG)

Comment: @MewX This is not a JUnit vs TestNG issue.  There is no "option" per se, the `Tasks` box should be a free form text field.  The `integTest` relates to the Gradle task defined in the OP's sample `build.gradle` file.  That task combined with the `integTest ` `sourceSets` defines which files/dirs are to be used to run integration tests.

Comment: But that means that every developer has to edit the run configuration for every integration test they want to run.

Comment: @AndyL You can save/share/commit your run configs.  It's not ideal, but it's an option 

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configurations-dialog.html

Don't forget to change your SCM config if you decide to go that route.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46058224/378151

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to configure IntelliJ to not use Gradle as a test runner, but to execute the tests with the built-in JUnit runner. This is just a configuration option in IntelliJ IDEA at the Gradle settings.

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle-settings.html#gradle_tests for details.