# Export/import project structure?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

Just asked at [Jetbrains forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200382555-IntelliJ-IDEA-Users), but it isn't too much activity there... so I haven't got any answer.

Is it possible to copy project settings to another project?, I'd like to export project modules, dependencies, run configurations and so on.

If IntelliJ can't do it, is there any plugin which has this feature?

Comment: For run configurations, this answer will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24642246/1168342

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a good question, actually I have same problem when I need to clone again my project from Mercurial SCM. AFAIK there is no standard JetBrains way.

But what I am doing usually - just copy following folders/files into the new project:

- `*.iml` (module description files)
- `.idea` folder
- maybe `*.ipr` too. I'm using maven, therefore I don't have such files.

Anyway all those intellij's configuration files are plain XML's. So if your target project is different by the structure - you can prepare them manually.

**UPD**
Also whether you will need to share configuration between team members - check this plugin:
[IntelliJ Configuration Server Plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4560)

**UPD 2**
Plugin above is deprecated. Now they have officially integrated it into intelliJ distributions.
https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/plugins/settings-repository

Comment: Yes, that's what I do, but that's a manual task I don't want to do anymore. It's paradojic that IntelliJ is the best IDE for automating tasks but that is not solved!

Comment: they have issue tracker where you can request some features. I have asked once. it took them ~2 years. but still it's here now :) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/dashboard

Comment: Was asked more than 2 years ago by another person, but rejected: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-83758 with a solution that doesn't convince me at all...

Comment: If you share a configuration (checking the box), you don't see the config in another project, so that solution doesn't work for me. Also you can't share your modules, libraries and so on, so for me that's not a solution.

Comment: The plugin is deprecated, I quote:
"Deprecated - please use [Settings Repository](https://github.com/develar/settings-repository) plugin."