# how can I export the call hierarchy for whole project

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, eclipse-plugin, intellij-plugin

We can find out where a function is used by "Call Hierarchy". I want to extract the hierarchy of all the functions in the project and export it to a table like excel. Is there a known plugin for this? I use IntelliJ, but if there is an easier way to do this with Eclipse, I can move the project to Eclipse. If I don't have such an plugin, should I write a code about it? Which libraries should I use for this?

Other places where clickCancelButton () is used when Navigate / Call Hierarchy is performed for Management.clickCancelButton ()

```
    NadModeController.clickCancelButton()  
    TimeItemListController.clickCancelButton()  
    VoyageController.clickCancelButton()  
    UserController.clickCancelButton()  
    ItineraryUpdateController.clickCancelButton()  
    VoyageUpdateController.clickCancelButton()  
    ItineraryController.clickCancelButton()  
    UserUpdateController.clickCancelButton()
```

like this. For all functions in the project, I am looking for a way to do this all at once.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export/import project structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28676327/export-import-project-structure)

Comment: For instance, you can [write a standalone application using the Eclipse Java compiler](https://www.programcreek.com/2011/01/a-complete-standalone-example-of-astparser/) to get these data.

Comment: I'm talking about the "Call Hierarchy", which shows which functions are called from a function, and that all functions in a project are done in a single transaction and that it is exported

Comment: *"I am looking for a way to do this all at once"*, why do you need this?

Comment: Because we want to associate functions with test requirements to ensure traceability. To determine which tests are performed when a function changes. For this reason, all functions in the project are requested to be found

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303073/dependencies-analysis-tool-updating-regression-test-cases  my question as the same at link