# Save default run configurations in the repo for IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I need to add some flags for unit tests, and want to share them for all team members. [IntelliJ has a solution to share run configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642147/how-do-i-share-intellij-run-debug-configurations-between-projects), but default configurations doesn't have `share` checkbox:

[image]

Of course, these settings are stored in `idea/.workspace`, but I don't want to store to the repository all my stuff, like recent searches. Is there any solution to store default run configurations in the repository?

Comment: Please vote for this feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-65915.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround to pass common params to any project's JUnit run configuration which relies on IntelliJ IDEA's [feature of picking maven surefire settings](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206423669-Junit-Maven-surefire-plugin-settings).

So it's sufficient to add common params to the main pom:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <!-- force 7-bit default encoding to ensure that nothing depends on it -->
        <!-- take JFR profiling snapshot on each run -->
        <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=ASCII -Xmx512M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder -XX:StartFlightRecording=name=EcpTest,duration=999s,filename=target/ecp.jfr,settings=profile</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```