# Is it possble to have a project-level template run configuration?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, junit

For our unit tests I want to be able to provide some custom template configurations whenever a unit test is run (e.g. VM options, coverage runner). If someone clones our repository, I want their JUnit test configuration to be based off my provided template.

Is it possible to add a template JUnit configuration to my repository, and if so, where would it go?

EDIT: Note that my question is different from the [other SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642147/how-do-i-share-intellij-run-debug-configurations-between-projects) which share a single run configuration. I'm looking to share a *template* run configuration instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I share IntelliJ Run/Debug configurations between projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642147/how-do-i-share-intellij-run-debug-configurations-between-projects)

Comment: @PetrRastegaev I don't believe this would be a possible solution after looking at the answers to that question. It solve the case for sharing a single run configuration, but not for sharing a _template_ run configuration.