# Default Configurations in Run Dashboard in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, run-dashboard

Whenever I create a new workspace in IntelliJ, I need to add the default types for enabling "Run Dashboard" in the workspace. This is very cumbersome for me as I have certain types of configurations which I want to be available in Run Dashboard of every workspace.

I would like to configure the defaults for Run Dashboard which I would want to be available in any new workspaces I create so that I do not have to enable the run dashboard individually for every new workspace I create. Is this possible in IntelliJ?

I am using version 2019.1 now (the same problem exists in older versions as well)

Comment: Please see this thread. It is still actual. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642147/how-do-i-share-intellij-run-debug-configurations-between-projects

Comment: I knew I could share run configurations. I would like to share Run Dashboard across all my workspaces of different projects only on my system and not with anyone else in my team.

Comment: [The most popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24642246/8203759) in the thread says:

"You could copy `.idea\runConfigurations` and put it in the same location in all your idea projects."

Comment: Not a solution to me, I am expecting a default configuration kind of thing rather than having to copy on every workspace creation