# What is 'Store as project file' in 'Run/Debug Configurations' - JetBrains IDE's

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

**JetBrains IDEs** like PhpStorm, WebStorm, PyCharm or IntelliJ have **Run/Debug Configurations**.

When creating or modifying a configuration, you can select a **checkbox** with a label **"Store as project file"**.

From what I have seen, this will create a XML representation of the configuration and store the XML file inside a directory (defaults to `.run`).

**What exactly is the benefit / intended use of this?**

Comment: *"this will create a XML representation of the configuration"* All config files are XML based anyway.

Comment: *"What exactly is the benefit / intended use of this?"* Ability to share it via VCS with other team members (or easier copying files between projects etc) and be able to select what to share (i.e. exclude from syncing etc). With that option unchecked it will be stored together with many other things in a common `workspace.xml` file.

Comment: Thank you for your explaination @LazyOne. After refining my search, I stumbled upon this SO thread which explains further how you can share Run/Debug configurations. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642147/how-do-i-share-intellij-run-debug-configurations-between-projects